# VLC plugin blocks Modal Popup on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal, vlc

I have embedded a VLC plugin for video streaming on a HTML web page. The trouble is that it blocks the HTML popups like follows:
[image]

The Popup's z-index is set to maximum and following is the embed code for VLC plugin

```
<object id="vlc" width="430" height="250" events="True" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
    <param value="True" name="ShowDisplay">
    <param value="False" name="AutoLoop">
    <param value="True" name="AutoPlay">
    <embed id="vlcEmb" width="430" height="250" target="rtsp://****" loop="no" autoplay="yes" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin">
</object>
```

How can I put the Modal dialog on top.

Comment: Long time ago `<param value="transparent" name="wmode">` helped with some flash players, have you tried that? Also, maybe while modal is up, than hide the player? Can't tell more without link to website or working Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's an internal web page that's why no link to share. I have a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8o0Lwmk3/1/ but on fiddle it doesn't run the VLC player plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `embed` instead, this way (with windowless parameter):

```
<embed 
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
    pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
    width="430" 
    height="250" 
    target="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
    windowless="true"
/>
```

Embed [docs here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/).

> windowless: (since VLC version 2.0.6, only for Mozilla) Draw the video
>   on a window-less (non-accelerated) surface and allow styling (CSS
>   overlay, 3D transformations, and much more). Default: false